# Mutate returns data in wrong order dplyr is this a bug?

Tags: r, dplyr

I ran into an issue where `mutate()` in dplyr returns results in the wrong order.  My call to `mutate` uses data from an existing column as input, but the results are returned arranged as if the data was sorted before the `mutate`.

My specific issue uses the `dataRetrieval` package to get USGS/NWIS data from the web. In this example, I am retrieving the site names based on the site ID.  In the `dataRetreival package, site ID is a numerical code stored as a character.

```
library(dataRetrieval)
library(dplyr)

Gauges <- tibble( Name = c("Twisp", "Chewuch", "Andrews" ,"Met@Winthrop", "Met@Twisp", "Met@Pateros", "Met@Goat"),
                  ID = c("12448998" , "12448000","12447390", "12448500" ,"12449500","12449950" , "12447383")
)

## This works correctly with each of the station numbers
readNWISsite(Gauges$ID[1])$station_nm
# [1] "TWISP RIVER NEAR TWISP, WA"

## This does not work correctly
## Order is not right! Station does not correspond with ID  !!
Gauges%>%
      mutate(Station = readNWISsite(ID)$station_nm)

# # A tibble: 7 x 3
# Name         ID       Station                                      
# <chr>        <chr>    <chr>                                        
# 1 Twisp        12448998 METHOW RIVER ABOVE GOAT CREEK NEAR MAZAMA, WA
# 2 Chewuch      12448000 ANDREWS CREEK NEAR MAZAMA, WA                
# 3 Andrews      12447390 CHEWUCH RIVER AT WINTHROP, WA                
# 4 Met@Winthrop 12448500 METHOW RIVER AT WINTHROP, WA                 
# 5 Met@Twisp    12449500 TWISP RIVER NEAR TWISP, WA                   
# 6 Met@Pateros  12449950 METHOW RIVER AT TWISP, WA                    
# 7 Met@Goat     12447383 METHOW RIVER NEAR PATEROS, WA    

## This works, returning the correct site associated with the gauge number
Gauges%>%
      arrange(ID) %>%
      mutate(Station = readNWISsite(ID)$station_nm)
# # A tibble: 7 x 3
# Name         ID       Station                                      
# <chr>        <chr>    <chr>                                        
# 1 Met@Goat     12447383 METHOW RIVER ABOVE GOAT CREEK NEAR MAZAMA, WA
# 2 Andrews      12447390 ANDREWS CREEK NEAR MAZAMA, WA                
# 3 Chewuch      12448000 CHEWUCH RIVER AT WINTHROP, WA                
# 4 Met@Winthrop 12448500 METHOW RIVER AT WINTHROP, WA                 
# 5 Twisp        12448998 TWISP RIVER NEAR TWISP, WA                   
# 6 Met@Twisp    12449500 METHOW RIVER AT TWISP, WA                    
# 7 Met@Pateros  12449950 METHOW RIVER NEAR PATEROS, WA
```

Why is `mutate` rearranging the data in the middle of the process? Alternatively, what is going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To understand what is happening, instead of extracting only the 'station_nm', get the 'site_no' as well

```
library(dplyr)
library(dataRetrieval)
readNWISsite(Gauges$ID)[c('site_no', 'station_nm')]
#site_no                                    station_nm
#1 12447383 METHOW RIVER ABOVE GOAT CREEK NEAR MAZAMA, WA
#2 12447390                 ANDREWS CREEK NEAR MAZAMA, WA
#3 12448000                 CHEWUCH RIVER AT WINTHROP, WA
#4 12448500                  METHOW RIVER AT WINTHROP, WA
#5 12448998                    TWISP RIVER NEAR TWISP, WA
#6 12449500                     METHOW RIVER AT TWISP, WA
#7 12449950                 METHOW RIVER NEAR PATEROS, WA
```

Here, the 'site_no' is ordered based on the integer values of 'ID'. To correct this, we can either apply the function on each 'ID' one at a time with `rowwise`

```
Gauges %>% 
    rowwise() %>% 
    mutate(Station = readNWISsite(ID)$station_nm)
```

---

or `map` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
Gauges %>%
    mutate(Station = map_chr(ID, ~ readNWISsite(.x)$station_nm))
# A tibble: 7 x 3
#  Name         ID       Station                                      
#  <chr>        <chr>    <chr>                                        
#1 Twisp        12448998 TWISP RIVER NEAR TWISP, WA                   
#2 Chewuch      12448000 CHEWUCH RIVER AT WINTHROP, WA                
#3 Andrews      12447390 ANDREWS CREEK NEAR MAZAMA, WA                
#4 Met@Winthrop 12448500 METHOW RIVER AT WINTHROP, WA                 
#5 Met@Twisp    12449500 METHOW RIVER AT TWISP, WA                    
#6 Met@Pateros  12449950 METHOW RIVER NEAR PATEROS, WA                
#7 Met@Goat     12447383 METHOW RIVER ABOVE GOAT CREEK NEAR MAZAMA, WA
```

---

Or we extract both columns and do a `match` with the 'ID' and 'site_no'

```
Gauges %>% 
          mutate(Station = {
           tmp <- readNWISsite(ID)[c('site_no', 'station_nm')]
              tmp$station_nm[match(ID, tmp$site_no)]})
# A tibble: 7 x 3
#  Name         ID       Station                                      
#  <chr>        <chr>    <chr>                                        
#1 Twisp        12448998 TWISP RIVER NEAR TWISP, WA                   
#2 Chewuch      12448000 CHEWUCH RIVER AT WINTHROP, WA                
#3 Andrews      12447390 ANDREWS CREEK NEAR MAZAMA, WA                
#4 Met@Winthrop 12448500 METHOW RIVER AT WINTHROP, WA                 
#5 Met@Twisp    12449500 METHOW RIVER AT TWISP, WA                    
#6 Met@Pateros  12449950 METHOW RIVER NEAR PATEROS, WA                
#7 Met@Goat     12447383 METHOW RIVER ABOVE GOAT CREEK NEAR MAZAMA, WA
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun, Does `mutate()` default to sorting the output or is this a special case when the input column is a number stored as character or something?

Comment: @BrianFisher No, `mutate` would return the rows in the same order, but here the output from the `readNWISsite` is a `data.frame` with many columns and the sorting is happening in that level

Comment: Thank you @akrun, I think that's the part I missed.